# Calling a WCF asynchronously from an ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, concurrency, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a very established n-tiered ASP.NET MVC application that currently does everything synchronously; all controllers inherit from Controller rather than AsyncController.

What I want to do is to take one of the lower tiers (that literally every flow consumes) and put in an awaited call to a WCF.  Why await?  Well, I figure that it will reduce the overall thread-count and make the server more scalable.

However, I am not in a position to change any of the code outside of this tier.  So normally, one would change the calling methods from returning T to return 'async Task', and give the method name an "async" suffix, *e.g.*:

**from**

```
public string GetData()
```

**to**

```
public Task<string> GetDataAsync()
```

Okay, so I went about it with the following (cut down) code:

```
public ResponseObject GetSomething(RequestObject request)
{
    return MyMethodAsync(request).Result;
}
private static async Task<ResponseObject> MyMethodAsync(RequestObject request)
{
    using (var client = new Client(new NetTcpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(Url))))
    {
       await client.DoSomething(request).ConfigureAwait(true);
    }
}
```

When I run this code (F5), it gets to the line where it calls the "await client.DoSomething(request).ConfigureAwait(true);" and then, unfortunately, that's the last I see of my thread.  Occassionally it does return when I'm debugging (F11), but 99% of the time it doesn't.

- The non-ASYNC method works perfectly fine
- Debugging the WCF service shows it receives the request, processes it and returns
- Using a console app, this works perfectly.  It's only when I try this in one of my "middle" tiers of my web application that the thread disappears.
- I've tried with .ConfigureAwait(true) and .ConfigureAwait(false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: don't block on async code (your problem's the `.Result` which blocks, while its `Task` is a concurrent one, not a parallel one)

Long answer (and really good reading, too): [Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)